# Download File after submission in Contact Form 7 Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to make one form which give functionality like when user enter name and email,then PDF file starts download automatically.

And while i am applying this code in additional setting tab on submit button,it replay the error message like this.

I am currently working in local machine, i know error is in contact form 7 mail tab,but don't know how to fix it?

"There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later."

Here is my contact form 7 code:

```
<label> Name
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Email 
    [email* your-email] </label>

[submit "Download Now"]
```

Here is code that i write in Additional Setting for download PDF file directly when form is submitted

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/pdf-sample.pdf';"
```

Comment: replace localhost with your domain

Comment: I am working in local machine

Comment: then what is the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Found solution for your need,just follow below stops,it can not send mail,but works fine in local machine as per your requirement.

1) Just paste below code in your Additional Setting tab in contact form 7

```
demo_mode : on

on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/pdf-sample.pdf';"
```

2) Put below code in your .htacess file, after [/IfModule] and below # END WordPress

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: When I tried to paste the code in Additional Setting tab it shows 'Deprecated settings are used' . Then I checked on official website its given on_sent_ok and on_submit have been officially removed from Contact Form 7 5.0. You can use DOM events instead of these settings.

Comment: This is not anymore the possible solution, because the ´on_sent_ok´ has been deprecated since 2007, version 7.5.0 : https://contactform7.com/2017/06/07/on-sent-ok-is-deprecated/

Comment: No longer works. See Doran's answer for an up to date solution

Answer (score 3):

If someone is looking for an up-to-date answer since `in_sent_ok` is being deprecated, instead we can use:

```html
   <script>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'http://example.com/';
    }, false );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code is working for me: I made it with javascript

```
function force_download( file ) {
    pdf = window.open(file, '', 'left=100,screenX=100');
    pdf.document.execCommand('SaveAs', 'null', 'myfile.pdf');
    pdf.close();
 }
 on_sent_ok: "force_download('pdf_url_here');"
```