# Download pdf after submission Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, download, contact-form-7

I am currently using the mail to sent the pdf and I want them to `auto-download` once the contact form is filled.

How can I achieve this?

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430803/download-file-after-submission-in-contact-form-7-wordpress), and it does not cater my need.

I also tries `on_sent_ok: location ="pdf url"` but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into your htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
 ForceType application/octet-stream
 Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

add this code in your Additional Setting tab in contact form 7

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'your pdf file path';"
```

Try this I thin its word for you

Comment: I am already use this its work fine can you show me your error.

Comment: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration is  the error I am getting

Comment: There is missing any module in server try this once https://serverfault.com/questions/524966/how-do-i-get-apache2-to-parse-without-error-header-directives-in-a-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

The use of `on_sent_ok` has been [deprecated](https://contactform7.com/2017/06/07/on-sent-ok-is-deprecated/) since 2017.

Instead you need to add a function to your `functions.php` file. Here is an example.

Replace the `contactFormId` (999) and the download path respectively for your needs.

```php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'example_download' );

function example_download() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '999' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        window.open('https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/my-document.php', '_self');    
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: in my contact form, I have 1 dropdown list, I want to open a different link based on that dropdown selection after submission. How can I do that?